# Pipefail prevents command substituation from evaluating pgrep?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

My goal is to run a `pgrep lftp -c` command inside a `shell` script to check if `lftp` is already running.

But the following script never goes beyond "test" output.
Only if I remove the `pipefail` line completely, the script runs through. Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e pipefail 

echo test

EXISTING="$(pgrep lftp -c)"
echo $EXISTING
```

Comment: `set -e pipefail`? Or should that be `set -o pipefail`? The former enables the `errexit` flag and sets the first positional parameter to `pipefail`, while the latter enables the `pipefail` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note on shell scripting best practice guidelines: avoid using caps for your own variable names since that can cause naming collisions with the global environment variables. To take an obvious example, if you name a variable `PATH`, that will overwrite the global `PATH` variable meaning executables will no longer be found in the expected place.

Now, in the script you show us, there is no problem. It is working exactly as expected: you are using `set -e` which means "exit if any command fails", if any command returns a non-0 exit status. If `pgrep` doesn't find anything, it exits with a non-0 status, so your script ends right there.

You can see this in action if you try it manually:

```
$ pgrep lftp -c
0
$ echo $?
1
```

To avoid this, you can use `wc` instead of `pgrep -c`, because `wc` doesn't exit with a non-0 status if the line count is 0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e  

echo test

existing="$(pgrep lftp | wc -l)"
echo "Found $existing instances of lftp"
```

This produces the following output when no `lftp` processes are running:

```
$ foo.sh
test
Found 0 instances of lftp
```

If you want to set bash's `pipefail` option, you need `set -o pipefail`, not `set -e`. So maybe what you really want is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o pipefail 

echo test

existing="$(pgrep -c lftp)"
echo "Found $existing instances of lftp"
```

Comment: they've set the `errexit` feature, which makes the shell exit if any command exits with an error. `pipefail` would just affect how the exit status of a pipeline is returned, but there aren't any here.

Comment: @ilkkachu d'oh! `-e`, of course. Thanks, edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank's for the insight. Ideally I'd want to set both `set -eo pipefail`, but with this, egain the pgrep fails, even when using `wc - l` or course.

Comment: @membersound yeah, that's because `pipefail` makes the return status be "the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status". Since `pgrep -c` exits with `1` if it finds no matches, that makes the whole `existing=$(pgrep...)` exit with `1`, and `set -e` makes it stop the script. You can use `existing=$( ps aux | grep -c '[l]ftp' )` to get around that.

Comment: I could solve it with `$(pgrep lftp -c || true)`, so that I can now compine both `set -eo pipefail`.